# Initializing class issue using multiple ViewControllers (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm working with two view controllers in my XCode project. I passed a variable from the first View Controller to the second. And I keep getting this **Swift Complier Error: "Class SecondViewController has no initializers"  Fix-it > Stored property 'XScore' without initial value prevents synthesised initializers**.

This is how I passed the variable in the FirstViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(Segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var Destination = (Segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController)

    Destination.XScore = Score

    }
```

This is (part of) my Second View Controller:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var XScoreLabel: UILabel!

var XScore:Double = 0.00
```

I have tried many different ways to initialize this property even when it seems right to me without.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're casting `Segue.destinationViewController` as `SecondViewController` but your "second view controller" is called `ShopViewController`?

Comment: Can you tell us how `Score` is created?

Comment: Score is a double variable which starts at 0.00 and every time i press a button it adds 1. (Score += 1.00)

Comment: Are you very sure `Score` is a **`Double`**? You can't use `++` on a `Double` afaik.

Comment: That's not the problem, even if I delete it the problem persists

Comment: Well, I recreated it in a new project and with the code you've provided there are no problems (except you need an exclamation mark when casting to `SecondViewController`).

Comment: It's ok, I'll observe every detail of my code later. Thanks anyways for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. As Gabe points out, you are casting your destination as a type `SecondViewController`, but are showing  code for a different class, `ShopViewController`.

You need to show us the declaration of `XScore` in `SecondViewController`.

If it's defined (in SecondViewController) as

```
var XScore:Double
```

then change it  to

```
var XScore:Double  = 0
```

or

```
var XScore:Double? = nil
```

(to allow for nil values)

Comment: The "shop" thing was a typing mistake, I just edited it. Can you please check this again, I see you have a lot of experience. Thanks.   I've even deleted the variable and I still get the error.